# Performing Shraddha for missing person

Tags: shraddha

If an aged person goes missing, when it is right time to perform Shraddha for that person? How long one need to wait before doing the final rites?

(Related to this question): in the olden days people used to go to Vanaprastha and then Sanyasa. So, they were likely to be quite away from native place and relatives. If someone dies in a far away thirth kshetra, how did the children get to know about death? If the person is of significant importance (like Dhritarastra's death in forest), it probably was reported by sages/Brahmanas. But how did ordinary people knew death of their parents when in forest dwelling or Sanyasa?

How the Shraddha date is fixed in such instances?

Comment: As far as I know, one had to wait for 12 years after a person had gone missing. If nothing about the person is heard within these 12 years, then he/she is presumed dead & his effigy made out of kusha is cremated followed by the respective sraddha rituals. The same procedure is applied in case of the person who has undertaken sannyasa.